# help with query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table having staffid and studentid in which staffid repeating number of times.

```
staffid | studentid
___________________
5       |     4
1       |     6
5       |     3
5       |     4
1       |     1
```

IN this way I want to select those staffid with their count in order.

```
staffid 5 (3)
staffid 1 (2)
```

Comment: SELECT staffid FROM enrll GROUP BY staffid ORDER BY COUNT( staffid ) DESC returns 3 rows ordering by count (staffid) While SELECT COUNT( staffid ) FROM `enrll returns 1 row and count number of staffid? Why so my count works different in orderby and in select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the counts in descending order, then there has to be an 'order by' clause in the query.

```
select staffid, count (*) 
from table_name 
group by staffid 
order by count (*) desc
```

Comment: You need to select the staffid if you are going to group by it.

Comment: @Ray - I added the staffid. The difference between my answer and others is that I have an 'order by' clause which the OP required.

Comment: yes I noticed yours was the only answer with the order by, but I held off on the +1 until the select clause was fixed. :)

Comment: SELECT staffid
FROM  `enrll` 
GROUP BY staffid
ORDER BY COUNT( staffid ) DESC 

returns 3 rows ordering by count (staffid)

While SELECT COUNT( staffid ) 
FROM  `enrll returns 1 row and count number of staffid? 

Why so my count works different in orderby and in select.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(staffid) FROM table_name group by staffid
```

Comment: @mu is too short : SELECT staffid FROM enrll GROUP BY staffid ORDER BY COUNT( staffid ) DESC returns 3 rows ordering by count (staffid) While SELECT COUNT( staffid ) FROM `enrll returns 1 row and count number of staffid? Why so my count works different in orderby and in select.

Comment: @Aditii: Your query that returns one row doesn't have a GROUP BY so the COUNT operates over the entire table at once.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to actually know which staffid each count is for, you need to include that column in the select list.

```
SELECT staffid, COUNT(*) 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY staffid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(studentid) from table group by staffid
```

Comment: You need to select the staffid if you are going to group by it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an SQL database, try something like:

```
SELECT staffid, count(studentid) 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY staffid
```